# Evaluating params before serializing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building some functions to retrieve data whether you supply some params or don't. It will be used mostly with a geolocator function. Since it may provide (or not) the location, the function should be able to handle that but I'm not able to do that.

Here is the code:

```
function getData(position,line,limit,attach){
        var JSONurl = 'getter.php';
        var params = [
            {   get: "stations",
                line: line,
                limit: limit,
                lat : position.coords.latitude,
                lng : position.coords.longitude
            }
        ];            
        console.log($.param(params));
    }
```

But it happens two things, $.param(params) give me undefined and also, when no position is supplied (so position is null) it gives me an error that it's not able to retrieve .cords o a null value (which is good).

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's the best solution but you can go for something like

```
var params = [
            {   get: "stations",
                line: line,
                limit: limit,
                lat : (function(){
                    try {
                        return position.coords.latitude;
                    }
                    catch(e){
                        return null;
                    }
                })(),
                lng : (function(){
                    try {
                        return position.coords.longitude;
                    }
                    catch(e){
                        return null;
                    }
                })()
            }
```

Of course, you can go for a non-anonymous solution too

Comment: Why not just `lat: position && position.coords.latitude`?  Also @AntonioLaguna anonymous refers to the anonymous functions, functions without a parent object, i.e. functions without a name.

Comment: There's two anonymous functions there, you can, for example, name them getLatitude() and getLongitude(), and call them for `lat` and `lng` properties

Comment: Ahh okay I didn't get! Sometimes the easier solution is just in front of your face.

Comment: Now that's solved but still stucked with the undefined. It logs "undefined=undefined"

Comment: From the jQuery doc, "If the object passed is in an Array, it must be an array of objects in the format returned by .serializeArray()" -- i.e., the objects in the array must be name/value pairs like `{'name':'SomeName', 'value':'SomeValue'}`.

Comment: And that's how the array is formed, hence my confussion!